# Passing field values under the hood

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application. When user successfully registers, I don't want - in the JSON body response - the hashed (or raw) password to be shown. However, I do have a test class in which I would like to test whether the registration process has been the way I wanted it to be.

The issue is that the `TestRestTemplate` that I use for making a request, receives a serialized model, thus disabling me from accessing any "under-the-hood" field that the password would be.

Here's the `UserResponseDTO` class that is wrapped into a `ResponseEntity` object when controller returns a response.

```
public class UserResponseDTO {

    private String username;
    private Set<Roles> roles;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    public UserResponseDTO(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Create a user")
    @DirtiesContext
    public void createUserTest() {
        String pass = getRandomPassword();
        var postResponse = postRequest("/api/auth/signup",
                createUserRequest("john", pass));
        assertThat(postResponse.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);

        String actualJson = postResponse.getBody();
        UserResponseDTO actual = toModel(actualJson, UserResponseDTO.class);
        assertPasswordHashedJson(pass, actualJson);

        UserResponseDTO expected = createUserResponse("john", Roles.USER);
        String expectedJson = toJsonString(expected);

        assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
        assertThat(actualJson).isEqualTo(expectedJson);
}
```

No matter what, the "encoded password" in the below helper method will be null.

```
    public static void assertPasswordHashed(String rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        assertThat(rawPassword).withFailMessage("The provided 'raw password' is null").isNotNull();
        assertThat(encodedPassword).withFailMessage("The encoded password is null").isNotNull();
        assertThat(passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword))
                .withFailMessage("The password's hash does not stand for request's raw one")
                .isTrue();
    }

    public static void assertPasswordHashedJson(String rawPassword, String userJsonResponse) {
        UserResponseDTO user = toModel(userJsonResponse, UserResponseDTO.class);
        assertPasswordHashed(rawPassword, toModel(userJsonResponse, UserResponseDTO.class).getPassword());
    }
```

How do I test this hashed password?

Comment: Write a unit test for the component that handles /signup requests. The test you show should be failing if a password *is* returned.

Comment: Hm. So what you say is that this unit test should solely check only for the JSON response of the request? How do I test for password hash then? Obviously, I could use the database directly, but let's say I want a more high-level approach. I realize that the process of serialization from JSON to a model class will omit the `password` field (thus I don't really get what's the point of `access` key in `@JsonProperty` annotation).